# Debugging with Qt 4.8.7 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, qt4

I have a fairly large project built using Qt 4.8.7.

Up until recently I have ben using Visual Studio 2010 for development and debuging (using the qt add-in).

I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 now and am not able to properly, for example, inspect the value of a QString (only partially, like the first letter of the string) anymore.

I tried installing the "new" qt tools thing without success.

Any advice on that topic?
Is this even possible with Qt 4.8.7 and VS2017 or do I have to upgrade the whole project to Qt 5 in order to properly debug?

Comment: Maybe you need Qt Visual Studio Tools http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/08/03/qt-visual-studio-tools-version-2-1-2-beta/

Comment: It only works with Qt 5, or am I wrong? Anyway, I installed Qt Visual Studio Tools, no changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more detailed answer for people who will pass-by. You can download qt4.natvis from [here](https://gist.github.com/gregseth/9bcd0112f8492fa7bfe7), and add it to the system-wide Natvis directory (%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers).

Answer (score -3):

I found a compatible .natvis file for Qt 4 on the net, directing VS17 to the file fixed my problem

Comment: Glad you've found the solution.Please mark your reply as answer which will let more members notice it.

Comment: Where did you find it though? Could you provide a link or paste the file contents here? https://xkcd.com/979/